# Connect Electron desktop app with hardware

Tags: electron

if I develop app desktop with Electron (atom). This app can connect with hardware, example barcode readers? How to?
[electron.atom.io](http://electron.atom.io)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know about 'other' hardware but "**most**" barcode readers need nothing but drivers on the OS, you will see they 'type' the code in your 'input' element :)